# Is Dynamic LINQ still in use and suitable for narrowing-down search results?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, filtering, dynamic-linq

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC3 application in C#.

I am trying to implement in my application a **"narrow-down"** functionality applied the result-set obtained from a search.

In short, after I perform a search and the results displayed in the center of the page, I would like to have on the left/right side of the page a `CheckBoxList` helper for each **property** of the search result. The `CheckBox` of each `CheckBoxList` represent the **distinct values** of the property.

For instance if I search `Product` and it has a `Color` property with values *blue, red* and *yellow*, I create a `CheckBoxList` with text **Color** and three `CheckBox`-es one for each color.

After a research on the Web I found this **Dynamic LINQ** library made available by Scott Guthrie. Since the most recent example/tutorial I found is from 2009, I was wondering whether this library is actually good (and maintained) or not.

In the latter case is **jQuery** the best way to implement such functionality?

Comment: Could you explain, how you obtain and render the search results (is it happening client- or server-side)?

Comment: I do it on the server side. When the user press the search button, the controller receives the request with the content of the textboxes and call a search function form my service layer. Then he receives the resluts wrap them in a ViewModel and send it to the View

Answer (score 5):

You can solve it by building the needed predicate expressions dynamically, using purely .NET framework.

See code sample below. Depending on the criteria, this will filter on multiple properties. I've used IQuerable because this will enable both In-Memory as remote scenario's such as Entity Framework. If you're going with Entity Framework, you could also just build an EntitySQL string dynamically. I expect that will perform better.

There is a small portion of reflection involved (GetProperty). But this could be improved by performing caching inside the BuildPredicate method.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item (){ Category = "Big", Color = "Blue", Value = 5 },
            new Item (){ Category = "Small", Color = "Red", Value = 5 },
            new Item (){ Category = "Big", Color = "Green", Value = 6 },
        };

        var criteria = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        criteria["Category"] = "Big";
        criteria["Value"] = 5;

        var query = DoDynamicWhere(list.AsQueryable(), criteria);
        var result = query.ToList();
    }

    static IQueryable<T> DoDynamicWhere<T>(IQueryable<T> list, Dictionary<string, object> criteria)
    {
        var temp = list;

        //create a predicate for each supplied criterium and filter on it.
        foreach (var key in criteria.Keys)
        {
            temp = temp.Where(BuildPredicate<T>(key, criteria[key]));
        }

        return temp;
    }

    //Create i.<prop> == <value> dynamically
    static Expression<Func<TType, bool>> BuildPredicate<TType>(string property, object value)
    {
        var itemParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TType), "i");

        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TType, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                    itemParameter,
                    typeof(TType).GetProperty(property)),
                Expression.Constant(value)
            ),
            itemParameter);

        return expression;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get why would you need the *Dynamic LINQ* here? Are the item properties not known at compile-time? If you can access a given item properties by name, eg. `var prop = myitem['Color']`, you don't need *Dynamic LINQ*.

It depends on how you render the results. There is a lot of ways to achieve the desired behavior, in general:

1. **Fully client-side.** If you do everything client-side (fetching data, rendering, paging) - *jQuery would be the best way to go.*
2. **Server-side + client-side.** If you render results on the server, you may add HTML attributes (for each property) to each search result markup and **filter those client-side**. The only problem in this case can be paging (*if you do paging server-side, you will be able to filter the current page only*)
3. **Fully server-side**. Post the form with search parameters and narrow down the search results using LINQ - match the existing items' properties with form values.

**EDIT**

If I were you (and would need to filter results server-side), I'd do something like:

```
    var filtered = myItems.Where(i => i.Properties.Match(formValues))
```

where `Match` is an extension method that checks if a given list of properties matches provided values. Simple as this - no *Dynamic LINQ* needed.

**EDIT 2**

Do you need to map the LINQ query to the database query (LINQ to SQL)? That would complicate things a bit, but is still doable by chaining multiple `.Where(...)` clauses. Just loop over the filter properties and add `.Where(...)` to the query from previous iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I guess the first `var prop = myitem['Color']` refers to a dataset. If I have a `List<T>`, I need to iterate over all the properties of T, therefore I need either Reflection or Dynamic LINQ. Do you see any other option?

Answer (score 0):

you may have a look at [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) from the author of C# 4.0 in a Nutshell

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by @Piotr Szmyd probabbly you don't need dynamic Linq. Iterating over all properties of T doesn'require dynamic linq. Dynamic Linq is mainly usefull to build complete queries on the client side and send it in string format to the server.
However now, it become obsolete, since Mvc 4 supports client side queries through Api Controllers returning an IQueryable.
If you just need to iterate over all properties of T you can do it with reflection and by building the LambdaExpressions that will compose the filtering criterion. You can do it with the static methods of the [Expression class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx).
By using such static methods you can build dynamically expressions like m => m.Name= "Nick" with a couple instructions...than you put in and them...done you get and expression you can apply to an exixting IQueryable

Answer (score 0):

LINQ implementation still has not changed so there should be no problem using the dynamic LINQ library. It simply creates LINQ expressions from strings.

You can use AJAX to call action methods that run the LINQ query and return JSON data. JQuery would populate HTML from the returned data.